# Movable panel in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

In the following code,
 is it possible to put `bins` in movable panel like the color  change panel.

The follwoing image shows one panel is movable but the other is not movable.

[image]

```
library(shiny)




# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
  shiny::tags$head(
    shinythemes::themeSelector()

  ),#taghead
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("bins",
                  "Number of bins:",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 50,
                  value = 30)
    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
    x    <- faithful[, 2]
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

    # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

How to make movable panel?
Please let me know.

---

```
**Answer: The following code makes a draggable panel** 




library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
  shiny::tags$head(
    shinythemes::themeSelector()

  ),#taghead
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins



    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(

      absolutePanel(
        sliderInput("bins",
                    "Number of bins:",
                    min = 1,
                    max = 50,
                    value = 30),
        draggable = T
      ),
      plotOutput("distPlot")
    )

)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
    x    <- faithful[, 2]
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

    # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Movable panels can be achieved with [absolutePanel](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.12.1/absolutePanel.html).